# Angular8 - [ngclass] performance Issue

Tags: css, performance, angular8, background-process, ng-class

I am using **[ngClass]** to choose css class based on material table row value. On mouse over event I am changing flag value which fetching cssclass and which is working fine. But when I am debugging it I realize that it creates background thread and chrome continuously checking **getIconCssClass** in background which might create performance issue. How to resolve it?

**HTML**

```
<mat-icon [ngClass]="getIconCssClass(element)" mouseOver="mouseOverCss(element)" mouseOutCss(element) ></mat-icon>
```

**.ts**

```
getIconCssClass(element: Object){
if(element.void && !element.mouseOver){
   return 'void-icon-normal-css';
} else if(element.v)
   return 'void-icon-mouseover-css';
}

mouseOverCss(element)
{
  element.mouseOver = true;
}

mouseOutCss(element)
{
  element.mouseOver = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just remove method from **[ngClass]** and added property in object element. Default **cssClass** added based on condition before rendering mat table.

**HTML**

```
<mat-icon [ngClass]="element.cssClass" mouseOver="mouseOverCss(element)" mouseOutCss(element) ></mat-icon>
```

Just changing **cssclass** on mouse over and out event instead of changing any flag.

**.TS**

```
mouseOverCss(element)
{
  element.cssClass= 'void-icon-mouseover-css';
}

mouseOutCss(element)
{
  element.mouseOver = 'void-icon-normal-css';
}
```

After some work around I found that when we use any flag in condition of **[ngClass]** method than angular create background process to continuous checking to method. we should always avoid boolean flag like **mouseOver** which is being changed in **mouseOverCss** method or avoid method itself to improve performance.